# Closing Form In VB6 With Keyword 'W' Or 'Ctrl+W' or 'Alt+w'

Tags: vb6

I Am New To VB6 , And Doing With College Project Can Anyone Tell How Can I Close My Form Without Using Any Command Buttons OR Control Tool.

Whenever Application Is Active OR Form Is Active , And User Press The 'W' Key Than Form Should Be 'END' / 'UNLOAD"
How Can I Do That ?

I TRIED THESE CODE :

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = 27 Then
Unload Me
End If
End Sub
```

BUT IT DIDn't WORK.

Comment: If you can't remember ASCII code for "W", just use `KeyAscii = Asc("W")`. Also I realise the convention in VB6 Is To Uppercase Every First Letter Of Each Word, but there's no such convention on StackOverflow, ALSO ALL UPPERCASE IS LIKE SCREAMING AT PEOPLE... feel free to edit your post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the Form's [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235137%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) Property is set to `True`, otherwise your Form will not process the KeyStrokes. I would also test for both upper and lower case.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 87 Or KeyAscii = 119 Then  '87 is upper case 119 is lower case
        Unload Me
    End If

End Sub
```

and if you want to check for Modifier Keys such as Control and Alt I would use the Form's [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445497%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) EventHandler instead.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If (Shift And 1) Then ' Test for Shift Key
        If (KeyCode = 87 Or KeyCode = 119) Then
            Unload Me
        End If
    End If

    If (Shift And 2) Then 'Test for Control Key
        If (KeyCode = 87 Or KeyCode = 119) Then
            Unload Me
        End If
    End If

    If (Shift And 4) Then 'Test for Alt Key
        If (KeyCode = 87 Or KeyCode = 119) Then
            Unload Me
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can You Tell Me That How To Shutdown PC Using The Same Key 'W' But Instead Of 'UNLOAD ME' What Should I Use ?

Comment: @DivyamSolanki You can use `System.diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "-s") ` make sure you import the `System.Diagnostics` Namespace.  For further information look at this [article](http://www.nullskull.com/a/840/shutdown-restart-or-log-off-your-computer-using-vbnet.aspx)

Comment: @DivyamSolanki `Shell "shutdown /s"`.

Comment: Can You Please Tell Me How To IMPORT 'system.diagnostics'

Comment: @MarkHall That's .NET.

Comment: @Boann You are right. I am out of the habit of thinking in VB6

Comment: @DivyamSolanki I had the wrong version of Vb for the answer I gave to your ancillary question. Boann's comment is what you will need to use.

Comment: @MarkHall : i hve one problem in vb..that after we connect ms-access db in form...how can we retireve data from db...eg : i made login form...but it should retrieve data from db...how can i do that...

Comment: @DivyamSolanki. That is a different question You need to ask that in new question.

Answer (score 2):

`Alt-F4` is a built-in hot key for Form Close in VB6 as in most other programs conforming to Windows Application Guidelines.

People also commonly have a menu option "Exit" and set its accelerator key to "x" so you might have a File menu with "F" and an option Exit with "x" and the user can type Alt-F, x to exit.  See Notepad or hundreds of other programs as examples of this.

Yes, you can use hackish approaches, but why?

Comment: I thought Alt+F4 was handled by Windows itself... isn't it?

Comment: Yes, unless a program removes it from the Control Menu.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110393